# iOS: can we stop user to switch between alphabets and number keypad for iPad

Tags: ios, ipad

I am developing an app for the iPad.

In some cases I am allowing user for a numerical input only. But the user can switch the keyboard from number to alphabets which I don't want. I am stopping user from alphabets but he can switch between keypads. So my question is, can I disable the switching between alphabets and numbers keypad options. This way I am stopping user interaction.

By applying keyboard type`numericTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;` it is showing numeric keyboard but user can switch between keyboards by pressing "ABC" button.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot stop the user to switch keyboard, but you can allow the user to write only numeric using below code. If the user presses other keywords then your textfield wont accept. Change macro as per your need.

```
#define ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS @"0123456789"

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField == yourTextfile)
    {
        NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS] invertedSet];
        NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
        return [string isEqualToString:filtered];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: yes i am using this code for enter numeric values. but i want to stop user for unnecessary interaction with keypad.